# How can I get out of this mess (need help getting back a username I used to own)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, username

I'm trying to get a `Facebook` username for my website's fan page (hereafter referred to as `myusername`). Unfortunately for me the situation is rather complicated as I didn't do things properly in the first place.

Here is what I did:

- as I already had a username with my personal account and wanted to
  reserve the name ASAP, I created a dummy user account and reserved `myusername` with it.
- some time after, I created a fan page for my website and asked some friends to like it.
- as soon as I got 25 fans, I released `myusername` from the dummy account (by changing it to something else) in an attempt to use it for my fan page.

Here is the situation now:

- `myusername` is no longer used by the dummy account (nor by any other account as when I go to `/myusername` I get the `The page you requested was not found` error).
- My fan page has more than 25 fans and I can set a username.
- When I check the availability for `myusername` it says that it's not available.
- That's been the case for months now.

The solutions I see:

1. Wait longer and hope `myusername` will eventually become available
   (I don't like that option).
2. Contact `Facebook` via the [Reporting a Violation or Infringement of Your Rights](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/208282075858952) form and try to get them to manually give me
   `myusername` (I own the Trademark in several countries, including
   `US` and `Canada`).

**Do you see any other solutions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered your own question. Go with the solution #2 that you posted in your question. Since you own the trademark the process should go pretty smoothly.

Comment: Even if in the first place I violated `Facebook`'s terms and conditions by creating a dummy account to reserve `myusername`?

Comment: You still own the trademark. At the worst the dummy account violated their *TOS*.

Comment: The username was eventually released after a couple of months and I could reserve it again :)